# Method in swift extension of an Objective-C class can not be access from .m file

Tags: ios, swift

Method in Swift extension of an Objective-C class can not be access from `.m` file

I have a bridge header:

```
extension foViewController {

   public func gome()
    {
        print("Hi");           
    }
}
```

I can't call method like `[self gome];` in `viewdidload` of `.m` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access Swift files in Objective-C classes, we have to add an import.

For example, if the project name is "De", add:

```
#import "De-Swift.h"
```

Only then we can access Swift files in Objective-C.

Comment: With swift 4, you must add '@objc' prior to function declaration to guarantee the visibility from Obj-C code

Comment: You can't use @objc in a Swift extension (unless it's a concrete extension)